# Console with data like in FireFox

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to get response data from Chrome like FireFox in developer tools ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can!

Open the "Inspection tool" with Crtl+Shift+I, then switch to the "Network" tab, it will asks you to reload the page to see every request/response. Do that and click the request you want to examinate under the "Name" section and switch again to the "Response" tab.